# How to trim the size of Key in a javascript object

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a JSON object like this

```
 var response = [{"2017-04-19T18:00:12+05:30":{"command":"00","device_id": "THB1", "voltage": "229", "e1": "00.00", "date_time":"18:00:12"}},{"2017-04-20T15:00:12+05:30":{"command":"00","device_id": "THB1", "voltage": "229", "e1": "00.00", "date_time":"15:00:12"}}]
```

I want to convert it to something like this

```
[{"2017-04-19":{"command":"00","device_id": "THB1", "voltage": "229", "e1": "00.00", "date_time":"18:00:12"}},{"2017-04-20":{"command":"00","device_id": "THB1", "voltage": "229", "e1": "00.00", "date_time":"15:00:12"}}]
```

I have tried this

```
for(var key in response){
    if(response.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        key = key.substring(0,10);
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work. Where am I going wrong?

Quick edit:
The current answers seem to be working but there are some objects having same date but different time. Hence the output only shows data for one particular time. Is there any way I can overcome this. For example:

```
var response = [{"2017-04-19T18:00:12+05:30":{"command":"00","device_id": "THB1", "voltage": "229", "e1": "00.00", "date_time":"18:00:12"}},{"2017-04-19T15:00:12+05:30":{"command":"00","device_id": "THB1", "voltage": "229", "e1": "00.00", "date_time":"15:00:12"}}]
```

I would like this to output this to something like

```
[{"2017-04-19":[{"command":"00","device_id": "THB1", "voltage": "229", "e1": "00.00", "date_time":"18:00:12"},{"2017-04-19T15:00:12+05:30":{"command":"00","device_id": "THB1", "voltage": "229", "e1": "00.00", "date_time":"15:00:12"}]}]
```

Comment: Can you please post the current output instead of «that doesn't work» ?

Comment: I was getting the input as output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this , this should solve your problem

```
      var response = [{"2017-04-19T18:00:12+05:30":{"command":"00","device_id": "THB1", "voltage": "229", "e1": "00.00", "date_time":"18:00:12"}},{"2017-04-19T17:00:16+05:30":{"command":"008550","device_id": "THUGHGB1", "voltage": "229", "e1": "00.00", "date_time":"18:00:12"}},{"2017-04-20T15:00:12+05:30":{"command":"00","device_id": "THB1", "voltage": "229", "e1": "00.00", "date_time":"15:00:12"}}]

                         var newResponse = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
          for (var key in response[i]) {
              var newKey = key.substring(0, 10);

              var newObj = {};
              if (newResponse.length) {
                  for (var j = 0; j < newResponse.length; j++) {
                      for (var newIdx in newResponse[j]) {
                          if (newIdx === newKey) {
                              newObj[key] = response[i][key];
                          } else {
                              newObj[newKey] = response[key]
                          }
                      }
                  }
              } else {
                  newObj[newKey] = response[key]
              }
              newResponse.push(newObj)
          }
      }
response = newResponse;
```

Comment: Thanks that helped. But I have an issue when dealing with data having the same date but a different time. Edited the question for more details. Please check it out

Answer (score 1):

In your case the issue is you are referring to `response` which is an array of object. But you need `response[0]` ti get the element from 0th index

```js
var response = [{
  "2017-04-19T18:00:12+05:30": {
    "command": "00",
    "device_id": "THB1",
    "voltage": "229",
    "e1": "00.00",
    "date_time": "18:00:12"
  }
}]

for (var key in response[0]) {
  if (response[0].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
   // creating substring from key name
    var x = key.substring(0, 10);
    // in same object creating a new key & value using the 
    // substring and previous value
    response[0][x] = response[0][key]
    // deleting the old key
    delete response[0][key];
  }
}
console.log(response)
```

Comment: Thanks that helped. But I have an issue when dealing with data having the same date but a different time. Edited the question for more details. Please check it out